# How i can scrape the value using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

i want to scrape "data-lat" and "data-lon" values. But i dont know how i can do this. Please help, Thank you......................

```
<div id="gmap" data-lat="40.98947720463825" data-lon="29.031221866607666"


    Sub sahibinden()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim url As String
Dim x As Object
Dim y As Object

ie.Visible = True

url = "https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/is-ilanlari-egitim-kurumsal-egitim-ve-danismanlik-evlere-yatili-yatisiz-yabanci-uyruklu-elemanlar-araniyor-459508951/detay"

ie.navigate url

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = ie.document

x = HTMLDoc.getElementById("gmap").innerText

MsgBox x

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting any error on any line? What value messagebox shows for x?

Comment: "data-lat" and "data-lon" values. example ... x=40.98947720463825

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim objGmap As Object
Dim lat As String, lon As String

Set objGmap = HTMLDoc.getElementById("gmap")

If Not objGmap Is Nothing Then
    lat = objGmap.getAttribute("data-lat")
    lon = objGmap.getAttribute("data-lon")
End If
```